# Question on the update step of Bayesian filter

Tags: bayesian-estimation

The update step in Bayesian filtering is given as follows, in a textbook

$p(x_k|y_{1:k}) = \frac{1}{Z_k}p(y_k | x_k)p(x_k|y_{1:k-1})$,

$Z_k$ is defined as $\int p(y_k|x_{k})p(x_k|y_{1:k-1})dx_k $

I was able to derive the second term on the right .The steps are given below
$p(x_k|y_{1:k}) = \frac{p(x_k , y_{1:k})}{p( y_{1:k})}=\frac{p(y_{1:k}|x_k)p(x_k)}{p( y_{1:k})} $

$=\frac{p(y_k,y_{1:k-1}|x_k)p(x_k)}{p( y_{1:k})}$

$=\frac{p(y_k|y_{1:k-1},x_k)p(y_{1:k-1}|x_k)p(x_k)}{p( y_{1:k})}$

By Markov property and Bayes rule

$=\frac{p(y_k|x_k)p(x_k|y_{1:k-1})p(y_{1:k-1})}{p( y_{1:k})}$
$=\frac{p(y_k|x_k)p(x_k|y_{1:k-1})p(y_{1:k-1})}{p(y_k, y_{1:k-1})}$

Applying bayes rule to the denominator

$=\frac{p(y_k|x_k)p(x_k|y_{1:k-1})p(y_{1:k-1})}{p(y_k| y_{1:k-1})p(y_{1:k-1})}$

$=\frac{p(y_k|x_k)p(x_k|y_{1:k-1})}{p(y_k| y_{1:k-1})}$

Can someone explain how the denominator in the above equation can be written as

$Z_k$ = $\int p(y_k|x_{k})p(x_k|y_{1:k-1})dx_k $

Comment: I think we need the problem setup from your textbook. Specifically, the state update equations for x and y.

Comment: Please find the link to the book, [Bayesian filtering and smoothing](https://users.aalto.fi/~ssarkka/pub/cup_book_online_20131111.pdf) The above section is on page 54, chapter 4.

Comment: Thank you. I will start reading. May be a little while before I get back to you... But I will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to see the definitions, but based on your prior work (which I haven't checked thoroughly), we can already reach the final stage. You left off at $$ p(x_k | y_{1:k}) = \frac{p(y_k|x_k) p(x_k|y_{1:k-1})}{p(y_k|y_{1:k-1})} $$ which is a probability distribution of $x_k$ based on the left hand side. The term in the denominator is independent of $x_k$ (if I have guessed your model correctly). Therefore, it is an unknown positive constant. That is, there exists some constant $Z_k$ such that $$ p(x_k | y_{1:k}) = \frac{1}{Z_k} p(y_k|x_k) p(x_k|y_{1:k-1})$$ where $Z_k = p(y_k|y_{1:k-1})$.

Now let's integrate both sides.
$$ \int p(x_k | y_{1:k}) d x_k = \int \frac{1}{Z_k} p(y_k|x_k) p(x_k|y_{1:k-1}) d x_k $$
The left hand side is a probability distribution with respect to $x_k$, therefore it sums to $1$. Because $Z_k$ is independent of $x_k$, we can pull it out of the integral. Multiply both sides by $Z_k$ to obtain your answer,
$$Z_k = \int p(y_k|x_k) p(x_k | y_{1:k-1}) d x_k.$$

*Is $Z_k$ a constant with respect to $x_k$?*

We know that $Z_k = p(y_k|y_{1:k-1})$ in other words $Z_k$ is the probability of $y_k$ given all previous $y_{1:k-1}$ after integrating out $x_k$. Note that this is the same thing as $$Z_k = \int p(y_k|y_{1:k-1},x_k) p(x_k) d x_k$$
which (after integrating) removes all dependency on $x_k$. Therefore, as noted in the original response, $Z_k$ is constant with respect to $x_k$ and can be factored out of the integral.

This practice of marginalizing out a variable based on its prior is a common theme in Bayesian systems.

Comment: Sorry, I found some typos after posting. Tried to correct them all.

Comment: Thank you. I think the last expression is $$Z_k = \int p(y_k|x_k) p(x_k | y_{1:k-1}) d x_k.$$ . I'm not able to intutively understand how $$ \int p(x_k | y_{1:k}) d x_k $$ integrates to 1. Could you please explain? $y_k$ represents the measurement of the model, it is independent of the measurement and state histories. But $y_k$ is dependent on $x_k$ . For example, in the Kalman filter equations we have $y_k$ = $H_kx_k +$ noise. In such a case, can we take $Z_k$ out of the integral?

Comment: You are correct. I apologize again for the typo. I will correct it.

Comment: Do you understand conditional probability as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability

Comment: I understand $$\int f_X(x \mid Y=y)dx = 1$$  However,I am not able to relate this to 
$$ \int p(x_k | y_{1:k}) d x_k = 1$$ since the conditioning is on $y_{1:k}$ and not on a particular state of y .Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Those are essentially the same thing. Where is the confusion?

Comment: In the second expression $y_{1:k}$ is $y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{k}$ ,there are multiple y's,whereas in the first expression Y is conditioned on a single value of  y i.e Y=y. Do you mean the expressions are the same because $p(x_k\mid y_{1:k}) = p(x_k\mid y_k)$?

Comment: In the second expression, the $y_{1:k}$ is shorthand for $y_{1:k}$ being equal to something. So, instead of a known scalar value, you have a vector value. But otherwise, they are the same thing.

Comment: $Y=y$ versus, $y_0 = a$, $y_1 = b$, $y_2 = c$, etc.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether this statement is right?  $p(x_k\mid y_{1:k}) = p(x_k\mid y_k)$

Comment: I am going through the text still. I'll do some follow up once I'm done. It is possible that I have written something incorrectly for this model since I didn't know everything before diving in. I will follow up, but it may be a day or two before I modify my post. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Everything looks fine, you can pull out $Z_k$ because $x_k$ is not found in it. This same step is implied for the full posterior distribution in equation 4.9 on page 53. The expression $p(y_k|y_{1:k-1})$ is independent of $x_k$. I have edited the answer to show this.

Comment: What's the question? (A) and (B) are two equivalent expressions for $Z_k$, but I used (B) just to illustrate that $x_k$ has been integrated out of the quantity $p(y_k|y_{1:k-1})$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and attention.$$Z_k = \int p(y_k|x_k) p(x_k | y_{1:k-1}) d x_k.  (A) $$ 

 $$Z_k = \int p(y_k|y_{1:k-1},x_k) p(x_k) d x_k  (B)$$  $p(y_k|y_{1:k-1},x_k)= p(y_k|x_k)$ since $y_k$ is independent of $x_{1:k-1}$ I am not able to interpret how the second terms are equal.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not being more clear. I think you have everything you need. You don't need to worry about whether the individual terms are equal. The integrals are equal based on the algebra done previously in the answer. Since $p(y_k|y_{1:k-1})$ does not contain any $x_k$, it can be factored out of the integral and it must be equal to what is left. I suspect in this case, an appeal could be made to demonstrate some relationship (perhaps equality) in the terms, but whether or not one can do that, the integral equality still must be true.

Comment: Probably it was my mistake in comparing the two integrals.Thanks a lot for the wonderful illustration.